# Dataform fields won't appear

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, dataform

I am trying to learn how to use the Silverlight 3 **DataForm** control, because I need to define the DataForm fields myself in the XAML code, that is, I don't want to use the AutoGenerateFields property.
My problem is: the dataform works perfectly when the AutoGenerateFields is set to true, but when I create a DataForm and set the fields manually and run the application, all I get is an empty blank rectangle where my form and its fields should be.

I created a blank Silverligh Navigation Application to test this, and below is the code of the Home.xaml page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <StackPanel>

        <!-- This doesn't work. It renders a blank rectangle -->
        <dataFormToolkit:DataForm x:Name="DataForm">
            <dataFormToolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel dataFormToolkit:DataField.IsFieldGroup="True">
                        <dataFormToolkit:DataField>
                            <TextBox Text="Test1" />
                        </dataFormToolkit:DataField>
                        <dataFormToolkit:DataField>
                            <TextBox Text="Test2" />
                        </dataFormToolkit:DataField>
                        <dataFormToolkit:DataField>
                            <TextBox Text="Test3" />
                        </dataFormToolkit:DataField>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dataFormToolkit:DataForm.EditTemplate>
        </dataFormToolkit:DataForm>

        <!-- This works. -->
        <dataFormToolkit:DataForm x:Name="DataForm2"/>

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

To make the second DataForm work, I simply created a Person class, and put the following in **Home.xaml.cs**:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Person client = new Person { Age = 10, DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1980, 10, 20), FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    DataForm2.CurrentItem = client;
}
```

You can see what happens when I run the application:

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know what's wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get something to appear I had to add:

```
        DataForm.CurrentItem = client;
```

to the code.

This just displayed three text boxes with no labels and the entries "Test1", "Test2" and "Test3". Is this what you were expecting?

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) samples page has an example of a template driven data form and it's XAML looks like this:

```
        <dataform:DataForm x:Name="dataForm" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="400" MaxWidth="500" Margin="4" Grid.Column="1">
            <dataform:DataForm.EditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <dataform:DataField>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </dataform:DataField>
                        <dataform:DataField>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </dataform:DataField>
                        <dataform:DataField>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </dataform:DataField>
                        <dataform:DataField Label="Calendar">
                            <controls:Calendar></controls:Calendar>
                        </dataform:DataField>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dataform:DataForm.EditTemplate>
        </dataform:DataForm>
```

And there's the line:

```
        DataContext = Contact.People;
```

in the code behind. (The class `People` is defined elsewhere as far as I can work out)

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. Thank you very much :) I don't get why it's necessary to add that line in the code behind, though. Can't I create a blank form that isn't bound to anything? I just wanted to work on the looks of the dataform, so I thought I wouldn't have to set CurrentItem.

Answer (score 1):

I also found it quite surprising that you need to bind to something before the form will even appear.

If you're trying to bind to a single item you need to do this :

```
 CurrentItem="{Binding Customer}"
```

or - if you're in a user control, just

```
 CurrentItem="{Binding}"
```

and then in the parent control

```
<my:AddressControl DataContext="{Binding Customer}"/>
```

Here's the full dataform:

```
<dt:DataForm Name="dfAddress" AutoGenerateFields="False" CurrentItem="{Binding}">
    <dt:DataForm.EditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel>
                <dt:DataField Label="First Name">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource FieldTextBoxStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
                </dt:DataField>
                <dt:DataField Label="Last Name">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource FieldTextBoxStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
                </dt:DataField>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
  </dt:DataForm.EditTemplate>
</dt:DataForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the CurrentItem="" in xaml. In this way, you dont need to actual bind it to anything and at the same time, work on the dataform looks :)